# JSON parsing Promise not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, typescript

I am creating a Promise which is supposed to add any numbers found in an array/JSON object.

add() is supposed to take in a string of urls, and output the sum of those urls.

The way I have done it is as follows:

I have created a helper function called parse, which takes in a string (the url) and should output the JSON object located at the url.

My problem is that at the area denoted by the $$$$, the object `jsonObject` is the correctly parsed JSON object. But, at the area denoted by the ****, immediately after where I call parse, the `parsedObj` is no longer the correctly parsed JSON object.

For example, if I parse a JSON object containing `[ 1, 2, 5, 4 ]`, I will get `jsonObject = 1,2,5,4` but `parsedObj = [object Promise]`.

Why is `parsedObj` an array of [object Promise] and not `1,2,5,4`?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Harper04 Sorry what's that?

Comment: can you please log the `url` parameter in the $$$$ section? are you sure that the returned element is a string?

Comment: Hi @briosheje, thanks for your response. I have done that and ```url``` is a string.

Comment: @chisquared a working example code demonstrating your problem in a runnable enviroment  https://jsfiddle.net/  there are a few of these platforms.  Helps us working directly with your code.

Comment: @Harper04 https://jsfiddle.net/c85ka9d7/#&togetherjs=ea5QBuwEev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse(url: string): any` returns a Promise not your jsonObject

So

```
                Log.trace("url: " + s.toString());
                let parsedObj = that.parse(s);
                Log.trace("parsedObj: " + parsedObj); // ****
```

really is asynchronous.
You'll get the jsonObject by using

```
parsedObj.then(function(jsobObject){
                for (var elmt of jsobObject) {
                    if (elmt.isNumber()) {
                        sum += elmt;
                        countNums++;
                    }
                    Log.trace("sum: " + sum);
                }

                Log.trace("sum: " + sum);
})
```

You'll want to store your parsedObj (your Promises) in an array to use another Promise.all() to fullfill your parent promise when all work is done

Comment: thanks very much for your effort in doing this. I now see where I went wrong. One last thing though, it is complaining that ```jsobObject``` is of type any. Do you know what the best way to remedy this would be? I am not too familiar with JSON.

Comment: Seems like you are using typescript which is a superset of javascript. Just look into the typescript documentation which type you could set.
like function(jsonObject:object) (if something like object exists...)

Comment: Correct. Much appreciated again. Have a great day.

Comment: sorry one more follow up if you don't mind. For some reason, the sum is never correctly calculated. Instead, a fail occurs, returning the error saying that no number was provided. I suspect this is because the if statement with fulfill() is getting executed prior to the then()? Any tips on how I could go around that?

Comment: please look at @Thomas answer for that. I did only answer your question and pointed out that you should revisit your control flow. He did all the cleanup on top - you really should write this his way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're under the assumption that `parse()` would return the resolved just because there is a `Promise.all()` in your code.

Since your code is to complicated and you're using the deferred antipattern, I've cleaned up your code.

```
parse(url: string): any {
    let rp = require('request-promise-native');
    return rp({ uri: url })
        .then(
            JSON.parse, 
            function(err){ 
                throw "Error: URL could not be retrieved" 
            }
        );
}


add(urls: string[]): Promise<number> {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(this.parse))
        .then(function(arrays) {
            let emptyArray = [];
             //flatten
            let numbers = emptyArray.concat.apply(emptyArray, arrays)
                //remove non-numeric entries
                .filter(function(v){
                    return v.isNumber();
                });

            if(0 === numbers.length){
                throw "Error: No number was provided";
            }

            //sum
            return numbers.reduce(function(a,b){ 
                return a+b;
            });
        });
}
```

Although, I've left out the logs.

any questions?

Comment: really cool use of map at Promise.all(urls.map(this.parse)) and much better than nesting Promise.all()s